# Trouble adding Case Comments Update using Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, case-comment

[image]

I'm having a difficult time getting my Flow to update the comment section on a Case. I'm looking to build a flow that allows users to transfer cases and leave a comment as to why. I am able to get the case to transfer to a new owner but the comments are not being updated on the case. Here is what I have for the comment update section in Flow.

---

**UPDATE**

It is still not working after implementing the following from an answer:

[image]

Comment: It's great that you updated your question to include that you tried implementing what I put in an answer; however, it is best if you add that information as an "update" to the end of the question. If a question is completely rewritten, it usually makes any existing comments and/or answers not make sense, and can be confusing to future readers. So I just edited your post to put your original screenshot back in, and I added a comment to sound like it came from you - please modify if you don't like it or it is an inaccurate statement.

Comment: I just realized, when editing the newest answer, that your update has `new_owner > Record Id` as the value for `ParentId` field. I am assuming that `new_owner` is a User; however - as stated in my answer - the `ParentId` needs to the `Id` of the *Case* record.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

Update the **Case Comment** object:

[image]

And the *Parent ID* field with the `Id` of the Case:

[image]

And the *Body* field with your comment text:

[image]

And the *Published* field set to TRUE:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the fields but I"m still a bit puzzled as to exactly what to put for the field associated with the ParentId. Should ParentId = recordId? Where I'm getting caught up at is in identifying how the case is identified for updating.

Comment: Did you include a *Create Records* step on the **Case Comment** object some time after this element/step?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new create element and a text template

Text Template resource should contain the body of your comment

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| How many records to create | One |
| How to set the record fields | Use separate resources, and literal values |
| Object | Case Comment |
| Field: CommentBody | Value: Comment Text Template |
| Field: ParentId | Value: Record.CaseId |

[image]